# What was everyday life in Mexico like during the early days of WWII?

Tags: world-war-two, mexico, game

I am curious to know what everyday life might have been like for a trio of American foreigners in the northern, near-border regions of Mexico during the early days of World War Two. Specifically, I am interested in knowing how they would have been treated by the people and the government, the technological level of early-WWII Mexico, and what it would have looked like in a fairly metropolitan area close to the border.

Note: This information is for a WWII-era RPG i'm GMing in which the players have decided to evade drafting by fleeing to Mexico (go figure).

Comment: Is it too broad, or just vague? This is not a proper question for the site.

Comment: Specifically, how would they have been treated by the natives and the government?

Comment: Rural areas or at a border town like Tijuana?

Comment: Definitely a border town. It is primarily metropolitan.

Comment: So, would that be October, 1939, or January, 1942?

Comment: Around 1939-1940.

Comment: Trotsky got icepicked. That's about the only interesting thing.

Comment: @Megalonychidae It is still too broad. It would be better if you were to split it into three different posts. One for technological level of WW2 Mexico, one for attitude of Mexicans regarding Americans, thirdly about life in Metropolitan Mexico during WW2.